# Route53 doesn't propagate to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, domain-name

I registered an .link domain name with Route53 and experimented a little bit with it. 
First I created an record to route traffic to my S3 static webpage. After that I deployed an Elastic Beanstalk app and tried to route the traffic to the Elastic IP of my EB instance. 
I am getting the whole time "no response" messages. When I do a test on the record set, I am getting the right IP in the "Response returned by Route 53" field.
I even done an whois request on my domain name, and nowhere were mentioned the information I entered during the registration.

Did I forget something or do I have to pay attention on something?

I noticed that the Domain name status code is blank for this domain name.

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if there's any other info I can provide about my setup to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blank Domain name status has nothing to do with the problem. The domain name works now and the Domain name status is still blank.

The problem was that the nameservers for the registered domain not matched the nameservers of the hosted zone. The support provided me the correct namerservers, I replaced the nameservers of the registered domain and the hosted zone with the one the support provided me and everything works fine.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I'm using Route53 to route traffic to an Elastic Beanstalk instance.

In EB, under "All Applications", I have a running application with a URL ending in ".elasticbeanstalk.com"

[image: Elastic Beanstalk App]

Then, in Route 53, I have a record which routes a particular subdomain to my EB URL:

[image]

Comment: I tried it with the IP and URL. IT doesnt work in both cases.